# JOptionPane won't accept long type

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, joptionpane

I am having an issue within the parameters of my `JOptionPane MessageDialog`. I am trying to print out the list of usernames that are in my array list, along with there corresponding time stamp for when they logged in.

Code:

```
Calendar currentDay = Calendar.getInstance();

loginArray.add(userName);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, loginArray.get(0), currentDay.getTimeInMillis());
```

Error:

> `gui.java:299: error: no suitable method found for showMessageDialog(<null>,String,long)`

I understand what the error is saying, but I have tried to cast it to a String, etc and it won't allow me to... Should I try `toString`?

Comment: What do the three parameters of the `showMessageDialog` method expect?

Comment: loginArray will be a username and the current day will be a time stamp of when the user logged in.

Comment: No, that wasn't my question. What does the method expect? What types? And what will it do with them? See the javadoc.

Comment: No, he's asking you to check the java doc, the API for JOptionPane as it will tell you **exactly** what parameters are necessary and available for this method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it doesn't, the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) clearly state

```
showMessageDialog(
    Component parentComponent, 
    Object message, String title, 
    int messageType)
```

And I don't know why you're trying to pass `currentDay.getTimeInMillis` as the message parameter, the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog%28java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int%29) state

> messageType - the type of message to be displayed: ERROR_MESSAGE, INFORMATION_MESSAGE, WARNING_MESSAGE, QUESTION_MESSAGE, or PLAIN_MESSAGE

Some idea of what you are tying to achieve might help use to provide you with a solution

StackOverflow is not a replacement for the Java Docs or [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: @javaGeek We're happy to help, but you need to make the effort to solve the issues as best you can, the JavaDocs, tutorials and SO are great places to start, then, if you can't solve the problem, post a question, just highlight your efforts